# Scala inner classes

Tags: scala

I am struggling with using inner classes in Scala. I am trying to implement a tree that uses a subclass of Node. I keep getting the error that type Node is not being found. I keep getting the error in both of the constructors.

```
class avlTree[T] private (var root:Node) {
    class Node (val element:T){
        var leftChild:Node = _;
        var rightChild:Node = _;
        var height:Int=0;
    }

    def this(x:T) = this(new Node(x))

}
```

Comment: you cannot both define Node inside of avlTree, and use Node as a constructor argument for avlTree, as it isn't in scope when the constructor is run.

Comment: @DavisBroda ok thank you. I wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to do it that I was missing

Comment: @DavisBroda You should post that as an answer!

Comment: You can put `Node` into the companion class of `avlTree` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If `Node` is an inner class, this means each `Node` belongs to an `avlTree` and you can't create a `Node` without first having the tree it'll belong to:

```
val tree: avlTree[Int] = ...
new tree.Node(1)
```

So your constructor would mean that to create a tree you need to have a node which belongs to this tree and so the tree must already exist.